# MvvmCross Android binding in code

Tags: android, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a MVX aware activity that has a view model of type `AViewModel`. `AViewModel` has a property of type `BViewModel`. The `AView` creates an external function that creates a sub-view in code. The sub-view may look like this:

```
var editText = new EditText(context);
editText.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
editText.TextSize = 40f;

var textView = new TextView(context);
textView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
textView.TextSize = 40f;

var linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
linearLayout.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

linearLayout.AddView(editText);
linearLayout.AddView(textView);
```

The `linearLayout`is then added to the `AView`. When i run it, the view is displayed correctly.
Now i need to add binding to it.

The external code that creates the sub-view only knows `BViewModel`. It has no clue about `AViewModel`, so i tried to create a new binding context and owner

```
class BindingContextOwner : IMvxBindingContextOwner
{
    public BindingContextOwner(IMvxBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        this.BindingContext = bindingContext;
    }

    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }
}

var contentContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(this, this);
contentContext.DataContext = this.ViewModel.BViewModel;

var contentBindingOwner = new BindingContextOwner(contentContext);
```

where `this` is my MVX aware activity. then i pass contentBindingOwner to my external code and try to do the binding

```
var set = bindingOwner.CreateBindingSet<IMvxBindingContextOwner, BViewModel>();
set.Bind(editText).For(v => v.Text).To(vm => vm.Foo).TwoWay();
set.Bind(textView).For(v => v.Text).To(vm => vm.Foo)
set.Apply();
```

when i run the code, the view gets displayed correctly, but the binding does not work. Nothing happens, and i do not see any log messages that could help.

somebody an idea what i am doing wrong here?

EDIT: Now, i feel stupid. My code works perfectly fine. Problem was that i did not see the text view because the linear layout is horizontal by default. so the text view was out of view. Well, maybe this post is good for reference.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question and mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works, the problem is that the text view was out of view. See OP for details!